# Loop through a file directory to check if the file exists, if it does increment the version number if not create the new file

Tags: vba, for-loop, increment, powerpoint

Could someone please help me out with a way to loop through the directory of the current file and search for the file to see if it exists, if it does then count the number of files with version numbers already and increment the next number, if it does not exist then create the file like normal.

Basically I have a vba macro that allows you to extract a slide pack from a 'master template' which they are all stored. The user clicks on the pack that they want and the pack gets extracted and saved out into that same directory. My problem is there is no version control or file protection setup. Could someone please help me work out how to do a loop and increment the version numbers.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreatePack(control As IRibbonControl)

  Dim packName As String
  Dim Count As Integer
  Select Case control.Id
    Case "packbutton_B1"
      packName = "B1"
    Case "packbutton_B2"
      packName = "B2"
    Case "packbutton_TSD"
      packName = "TSD"
  End Select

  'Note: Attempt to remove characters that are not file-system friendly
  Dim Title As String
  If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count >= 9 Then
    Title = Trim(ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(9).TextEffect.Text)
    If Title = "" Then MsgBox "Warning: A project title has not been entered on Slide 1."
  Else
    Title = "(Project Title Not Known)"
    MsgBox "The title slide has been removed, the project name cannot be detected."
  End If
  Title = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Title, "/", ""), "\", ""), ":", ""), "*", ""), "<", ""), ">", ""), "|", ""), """", "")

  Dim path As String
  path = ActivePresentation.path

  If Len(Dir(path & "\" & packName & " Slide Pack - " & Title & ".pptx")) > 0 Then 'File exists

 ' If MsgBox("This will produce a pack in a separate PowerPoint file. Before extracting the pack make sure you have implemented a version number otherwise your changes maybe overwritten." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Your current file will remain open, and any pending changes will not be automatically saved.", vbOKCancel, "Slide Manager - Create Pack") = vbOK Then

  MsgBox ("File exists, the file name version number will be incremented")

  CopySlidesToBlankPresentation packName

  Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs path & "\" & packName & " Slide Pack - " & Title & Count + 1, ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation

  ActivePresentation.Save

  Else

  MsgBox ("This will produce a pack in a separate PowerPoint file." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Your current file will remain open, and any pending changes will not be automatically saved")

  CopySlidesToBlankPresentation packName

  Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs path & "\" & packName & " Slide Pack - " & Title, ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation

  ActivePresentation.Save

End If

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly your loop should look something like this

```vb
Dim fileNoVersion As String
fileNoVersion = path & "\" & packName & " Slide Pack - " & Title

Dim count As Integer
count = 1
While Dir(fileNoVersion & count & ".pptx") <> ""
    count = count + 1
Wend
```

This checks which files Version1, Version2, Version3... exist and returns the next unused number.